# List of figures: figure numbers appear in incorrect order

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, sorting

The List of Figures in my thesis sorts my figures based on the page number on which they appear. Instead I would like the figures to be sorted based on their figure number. The current sorting method leads to lists such as this:

> List of Figures
>
> 4.1
>
> 4.4
>
> 4.5
>
> 4.2
>
> 4.3
>
> 4.6

I would rather like the figure numbers to be sorted from first to last. The wrongfully ordered figures appear on the last page of the chapter due to size.

Is there a work-around to achieve my sorting wish?

The following is hardly a minimal working example, but I was not able to reproduce the situation without using my actual files. Note that I load a self-made "package" containing a lot of packages and page formatting. Here is a dropbox link to the compressed folder containing all files.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ptz9sl4dnydrua/LoF%20sorting.zip?dl=0

Comment: Well, normally figure numbers are sorted actually and they should increase with page numbers too, so this behaviour is strange, unless you made entries to the LoF manually.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Or did you change the `figure` counter value in between?

Comment: I have not done anything to change the figure counter. Some figures are \sidewaysfigures, though, but that should not be an issue. I will make a MWE.

Comment: I've downloaded your example and could track the wrong behaviour down to the fact of using  `\begin{figure}[H]` etc. Sometimes (most times?) it is better to drop the floating and just include the image with `\includegraphics`, using `\captionof{figure}{caption title}`. This requires the `caption` package, however